# How to correctly associate the relationship between lessons, roles and teachers(postgres)?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am trying to set up the database model for `lessons`(`session`) and `teachers`(`user`), and I have the following sql right now, which assumes `lessons` and `teachers` in a many-to-many relationship:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "user";
CREATE TABLE "user" (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email CITEXT UNIQUE CONSTRAINT email_length CHECK (char_length(email) <= 254),
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "session";
CREATE TABLE "session" (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    event_id INT NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "session_user";
CREATE TABLE "session_user" (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES "user"(id),
    session_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES "session"(id),
    UNIQUE (user_id, session_id)
);
```

Now I need to implement a new functionality of role, which every user may have different role in a session. For example, in session A user X is the host and user Y is the assistant, whereas in session B user X is the assistant and user Y is the host. How can I model this relationship?

**EDIT**

Is the structure the right way to do what I want?

[image]

Comment: A session_user many-to-many table with an additional role column seems like it should satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Yes I think so too, I will try and use `session_user_role`. Thanks

Comment: You can answer it in an answer, so I will mark it correct for you:)